# FastAI PyTorch Train_loss and valid_loss look very good, but the model recognize nothing

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, pytorch, fast-ai

**Update 1**

I’m thinking that it might be the mistake in my detector code.
So, here is my code for using the trained learner/model to predict images.

```
import requests
import cv2

bytes = b''
stream = requests.get(url, stream=True)
bytes = bytes + stream.raw.read(1024) # I have my mobile video streaming to this url. the resolution for the video streaming is: 2048 x 1080
a = bytes.find(b'\xff\xd8')
b = bytes.find(b'\xff\xd9')
if a != -1 and b != -1:
      jpg = bytes[a:b+2]
      bytes = bytes[b+2:]
      img = cv2.imdecode(np.fromstring(jpg, dtype=np.uint8), cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
      processedImg = Image(pil2tensor(img, np.float32).div_(255))
      predict = learn.predict(processedImg)
      self.objectClass = predict[0].obj
```

and I read the document of imdecode() method, it returns image in B G R order.

**Could it because of different channel data used when in training and detecting?**

Or

**Could it because that I trained with image size 299 x 450, but when detecting the input image size from the video streaming is 2048 x 1080 without resizing it?**

---

new to FastAi, ML and Python. I trained my “Birds Or Not-Birds” model. The train_loss, valid_loss and error_rate were improving. If I only trained 3 epochs, then the model worked(meaning it can recognize whether there are birds or no birds in images), then I increased to 30 epochs, all metrics look very good, but the model does not recognize things anymore, whatever images I input, the model always return Not-Birds.

here is the training output:

[image]

Here are the plots of learn.recorder

[image]

Here is my code:

```
from fastai.vision import *
from fastai.metrics import error_rate
from fastai.callbacks import EarlyStoppingCallback,SaveModelCallback
from datetime import datetime as dt
from functools import partial

path_img = '/minidata'
train_folder = 'train'
valid_folder = 'validation'

tunedTransform = partial(get_transforms, max_zoom=1.5)

data = ImageDataBunch.from_folder(path=path_img, train=train_folder, valid=valid_folder, ds_tfms=tunedTransform(), 
                                  size=(299, 450), bs=40, classes=['birds', 'others'], 
                                  resize_method=ResizeMethod.SQUISH)
data = data.normalize(imagenet_stats)

learn = cnn_learner(data, models.resnet50, metrics=error_rate)
learn.fit_one_cycle(30, max_lr=slice(5e-5,5e-4))

learn.recorder.plot_lr()
learn.recorder.plot()
learn.recorder.plot_losses()
```

Here is my dataset folder structure:

- minidata

  - train

    - birds (7500 images)
    - others (around 7300 images)
  - validation

    - birds (1008 images)
    - others (around 872 images)

Answer (score 2):

Your learning rate schedule is sub-optimal for this dataset. Try to first figure out the best learning rate for this network and dataset with 
[LRFinder](https://docs.fast.ai/basic_train.html#lr_find). This can be done by exploring the loss behavior for different learning rates with

```
learn.lr_find()
learn.recorder.plot()
```

Edit:

It looks like you are re-training the last layer in your network. Instead try training more layers from scratch. as:

```
learn.unfreeze(2)
```

Comment: hi nav, I actually have done it and the lr I used was suggested by the lr_find() method.  Here is the post where I posted more details about lr_find() related questions. After reading the question and my update 1 in that question, you probably see that lr_find() does not work properly.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59549092/fastai-lrfind-method-doesn-t-work-properly?noredirect=1#comment105280903_59549092  here i the link

Comment: Your loss curve is very chaotic. Indicating that the minimisation is failing. Please explore several learning dates until the curve minimises gradually. The search for learning rates should be in a log scale. Then I have a second set of recommendations for you.

Comment: thanks nav. What do you mean by "learning dates"? Could you please elaborate it? thanks

Comment: Apologies for the typo. I meant rates.

Comment: thanks, Nav. I have tried so far: 1e-3, 1e-2; 1e-8, 1e-3; 1e-5, 1e-3; 1e-6, 1e-4 etc.  However, the issue pattern persists: train_loss goes up and down.

Comment: hi @nav, please also see my update 1, it provides more possible cause.

Comment: You are mixing up model training with application logic. Regardless of the application error. I would suggest to first check the train and validation set images and get the model working well. The following is a good checklist. 1. Check If both train and valid images are same size & same encoding RGB or BGR etc. 2. Dump a single batch of images and see if its is visually consistent

Comment: After these checks. You will need to explore how close your pre-trained model is to the application you are fine-tuning for. If they are very different, you may have to train more layers for your application.

Comment: I can confirm that images in train and validation folders are in different sizes. But I have specified to re-size them when ```ImageDataBunch.from_folder(size=(299, 450)...)``` so checklist 1, shouldn't be a problem.  Yes, I use ```data.show_batch(rows=6, figsize=(14,12))``` in my Jupyter Notebook to see my images before training, they look very well resized to (299, 450). They are all in RGB format I guess, the BGR is only happened when using **cv2** to read image from the video stream

Comment: as to fine-tuning for my application. Could you please elaborate it? thanks

Comment: hi @nav, please correct me if I was wrong. but I think the 30 is not 30 layers in my network. it is the training iterations. here is the documentation : https://docs.fast.ai/train.html#fit_one_cycle

Comment: apologies. my understanding of the api was incorrect. See the edit. Basically you need to unfreeze more layers.

Comment: thanks @nav :) I have had a look at the document and I think you actually mean to use freeze_to() (https://docs.fast.ai/basic_train.html#Learner.freeze_to)? and to only unfreeze the last 2 layers, correct? if I assumed correctly, then it should be unfreeze() and then freeze_to(-2).   Only one question, how do you know how many layers should be unfrozen and re-trained??

Comment: " how do you know how many layers should be unfrozen and re-trained??" that my friend depends on how close your task is to the task the network was originally trained on. E.g if your Resnet was trained on imagenet & the bird class exists in imagenet. You can get away with retraining 1-2 layers. Else its higher. Its all emperical.