# FastAI lrfind() method doesn’t work properly

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, fast-ai

**Update 1**

I updated my lr according to " you want to be 10x back from that point, regardless of slope." and set it to
max_lr=-slice(1e-3, 1e-2)

And here is what I got

[image]

And the plots

[image]

What does this mean?

As you can see in the 2nd graph that

1. the loss was very good starting from 1e-08, but I never set my lr to 1e-08, why do I see this??
2. the loss went up and down between 1e-07 and 1e-04 and eventually it soared to almost 0.05 when the lr came back around 4e-05. What does this mean? Overfitting? How come initially when the Learning Rate was around the same value(4e-05) the loss looked okay?
3. from the Batches processed/Loss, I can see that train_loss and valid_loss went together and looked really well. This means the model was trained very well? If it was well trained, why the shot-up at the end of graph 2?
4. I have followed the rule about picking up the correct lr, why does not it work? **May I conclude that the lr_find() does not work properly?**

---

Here is my lr_find() plot

[image]

then according to its graph, I picked up the steepest slope section: 1e-2 to 1e-1 as my lr.

Here is the code:

```
learn.fit_one_cycle(20, max_lr=slice(1e-2,1e-1))
```

But here is what I got during training

[image]

And here are the plots for learn.recoder

```
learn.recorder.plot_lr()
learn.recorder.plot()
learn.recorder.plot_losses()
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

As you can see the valid_loss is getting worse cyclically. So my conclusion is lr_find() method doesn’t work properly.

How can I verify it?

If you want to see the entire code, here it is; the only difference is I use `to_fp16()`:

`learn = cnn_learner(data, models.resnet50, metrics=error_rate).to_fp16()`

https://forums.fast.ai/t/train-loss-and-valid-loss-look-very-good-but-predicting-really-bad/60925

Comment: Have you tried different lower learning rates (ex: 1e-5 and 1e-3). My hypothesis is that you are using a large learning rate that is causing these jumps in the error plane.

Comment: thanks @AhmadBaracat I have reduced the lr and please see my update 1, it has all details.